# How could I make Aurelia include my styles as external styles via <link>?

Tags: css, build, gulp, aurelia

I am trying to set up the conjunction of Atom editor, Sass, Typescript and Aurelia. This question is about Aurelia (installed via aurelia-cli) and its building system, I guess.

Well, I wrote style.sass for my component, then I required it in the component's view (app.html, for instance) as style.css. Fine, it works. But the content of compiled style.css gets included in index.html as internal styles, I mean everything goes inside `<style>`-tag, not through `<link>`. Also it seems that the corresponding .css file is never created at all. The stream just includes its content right in `<style>`-tag inside index.html.

How could I make Aurelia include my styles as external styles via `<link>`? In building task the last action is a build-plugin coming from aurelia-cli which is kinda black-box for me. Also aurelia.json is imported, so there should be a way to configure the needed behavior. A quick search didn't give me the answer, so here I am.

Comment: What process compiles your styles?

Comment: What do you mean? I use sass. The building task within Aurelia is process-css.js. The task-runner is Gulp. It all is going on in Atom editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution, and not completely what you want, but perhaps it helps. You can do the following (I took a new TypeScript project):

First remove the css includes from your views.

Then, adjust the `./aurelia_project/tasks/process-css.ts` task as follows:

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import * as sass from 'gulp-sass';
import * as project from '../aurelia.json';
import {build} from 'aurelia-cli';

export default function processCSS() {
  return gulp.src(project.cssProcessor.source)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(project.platform.output));
};
```

This will output CSS files in the `./scripts` folder. Then, adjust the `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` file as follows (remove css):

```
  {
    "name": "app-bundle.js",
    "source": [
      "[**/*.js]",
      "**/*.{html}"
    ]
  },
```

In your `index.html` you can now include the generated styles (or even in your components views).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about altering task file too. But I would like to preserve the `<require>` functionality for styles in views. Probably I should read the docs more in depths - it feels that there should be a way to do it by declaring something in aurelia.json. Anyway, thanks for suggestion!